# Should I implement method chaining?

Tags: javascript, dsl, method-chaining

I am writing a javascript DSL and want to know whether method chaining is common practice when implementing javascripts that allow several methods to be called on a single object. I come from a Ruby background where the use of instance_eval is more acceptable for implementing DSLs, so I would prefer to implement my package in a similar way, but I don't want to go against convention.

My options are, through example:

```
MyObject('test').method1(function() {
  console.log('hi');
}).method2(function() {
  console.log('bye');
});
```

or:

```
MyObject('test', function() {
  this.method1(function() {
    console.log('hi');
  });

  this.method2(function() {
    console.log('bye');
  });
});
```

I thought I would throw this out to the JS gurus to see what is the preferred way to implement this. I suppose this really is a matter of personal preference but there may be a more accepted methodology. Any thought?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, you should choose the solution you're most comfortable with. Both methods use chaining, but the bottom one has a callback where the value of `this` is the object, so it's basically exactly the same as the first one, except for the extra function call.

Comment: Thanks. I was just curious as to whether there was a convention that most JS devs follow, as I know jQuery tends to use a method chaining style.

Comment: It does, but so does both your examples, they aren't really different in any way, you would still have to create the exact same methods that are prototyped to whatever myObject returns etc.

Comment: @adeneo: I fail to see how the second example is chaining. Unless your definition of chaining is very different from mine.

Comment: @slebetman - when you do `this.method1()` it's chaining, just like when you do `MyObject('test').method1()`, same thing, the function is chained.

Comment: @adeneo: No, `this.method()` is just a normal method call. `this.method().method().method()` is chaining. The contrast of unchained method call is: `this.method();this.method();this.method();`. Chaining is when you don't have to type the object name repeatedly. Inside its own class, `this` is merely an alias for the instantiated object.

Comment: @slebetman - You're not getting it, when you call a function you do `functionName()`, when you do `object.functionName()` the method is chained to an object, otherwise it couldn't be called like that.

Comment: @adeneo: But that's not what is meant by "chaining". Prototype chain resolution also uses the word "chain" but means a different thing to "chaining". English is weird like that.

Comment: FYI, this kind of interface is called a [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: Another related concept is `function()()()` which looks like chaining but is actually partial function application (or in some cases currying)

Comment: @ahruss: Right, in javascript it's better known as chaining.

Comment: @slebetman - call it whatever you want, I call it chaining even if there is only one method chained to an object, and in this case it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @adeneo: It's not me calling it that, it's what everyone (except you) calls it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Comment: @adeneo: By your definition `myobject.method()` should also be called chaining unless you have a very different understanding of how `this` actually works.

Comment: @slebetman - if `myobject` has a prototyped `method` method that returns another object, that is indeed chaining, even it has only one link. I haven't said that `this.method1().method2()` isn't chaining, it clearly is, but if an object has a callable property that can be chained, why wouldn't it be chaining even with one method call, why do you assume you need two or more to calls it chaining. Anyway, I really see no point in discussing this, I believe I have a good grasp of what chaining is, if you don't agree, I don't really care.

Comment: @adeneo: Because in the second example the method doesn't return an object. He's not showing you his implementation. His unstated question is: `should my methods return this`. Or to put it another way: should my methods be chainable and is chaining an accepted idiom in javascript?